# trim strim in visual basic 6.0

Tags: vb6, trim

I am working in visual basic 6.0 and attempting to retreive the server of a Queue. So far the only way I have found to get this is from the path name (oQueue.QueueInfo.PathName) (which gives me: vdi***\testQueue02)

I would like to trim this down to just vdi***\

But I can not do it by number of characters because I have hundreds of queues all with different lenghts and also the servers may have different lenghts.

Is there any way to do this??

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it always the "first part" of the path name you are trying to retrieve?

`Dim newArray() as String = Split(oQueue.QueueInfo.PathName,"\")

Dim path = newArray(0) & "\"`

Comment: I had tried the Split function before but didn't realize it had to be in array.